# VB.NET UserControl does not receive parent form's events

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have created a usercontrol and added it to a form.
I would like to receive the form's event using Private WithEvents _Parent As Form.
But none of the events is being received.

The entire code of my usercontrol is attached.

Does anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Public Class UserControl1

```
Private WithEvents _Parent As Form

Public Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()

    _Parent = Me.Parent

End Sub

Private Sub _Parent_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _Parent.Activated

    MsgBox("activated")

End Sub

Private Sub _Parent_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _Parent.Resize

    MsgBox("resize")

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: When the constructor is called, there is no parent yet. Handle `Me.ParentChanged` to initialize `_Parent`.

Comment: declaring a variable `WithEvents _Parent As Form` means your control will get the events the form/control **generates** not those it **receives**.  As your code illustrates, those are private.  If you need to pass that info on, your form could Raise new events effectively passing the event down the food chain.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586755/how-can-page-events-be-handled-from-a-usercontrol-vb-net?rq=1 for a better solution.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you! Can you make your comment the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the constructor is called, there is no parent yet (Windows Forms controls are added to their parents after the class is created). `Me.Parent` returns `Nothing` at this point.

Handle `Me.ParentChanged` to initialize `_Parent`:

```
Private Sub UserControl1_ParentChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.ParentChanged
    _Parent = Me.Parent
End Sub
```